# Methods, other than $project, to Limit Data in MongoDB View After $lookup and $unwind

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am running MongoDB version 3.4. In my aggregation pipeline, if I do a `$lookup` followed by an `$unwind` late in my pipeline, and I want to limit the fields that appear from that `$lookup`, are my only two options to either 1.) add another `$project`, including all the data I want to appear for the document with `{ "name" : 1 }` etc, or to add a `$project` stage *excluding* all of the data I don't want `{ "name" : 0 }`, etc?

I ask because, either way, that leaves me with a LOT of fields to either specifically include, or exclude. That's why I'm wondering, in version 3.4, if there are any other options that would allow me to limit the data appearing from that late `$lookup` and `$unwind` other than using `$project` again?

Comment: Please post your query as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no such option in 3.4, other than manually excluding or including fields using `$project`. And as long as it won't bloat over the BSON limit, it shouldn't be a problem.

Starting from 3.6, you can use the [new variant of `$lookup` stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) with an additional `pipeline`. But even with that, you'll have to use `$project` on the collection you are joining from:

```
db.collectionx.aggregate([
  // ...
  {$lookup: {
    from: 'collectiony',
    let: {field: '$field'},
    as: 'y',
    pipeline: [
      {$match: {$expr: {$eq: ['$field', '$$field']}}},
      {$project: {
        fieldA: 0,
        fieldB: 0,
        fieldC: 0
      }}
    ]
  }},
  // ...
])
```